Apache Tomcat 500 error with no trace of error in logs
We're doing some load testing using jmeter against our software that runs in Tomcat. We've discovered that above a certain threshold, we start to see random HTTP 500 errors come back with the message "The call failed on the server; see server log for details". However, there are no obvious log entries, either in our own error log or in catalina.out.
The closest thing I've been able to find is this, but there are only a small handful of these errors, and there are not as many as what errors we see in jmeter:
28-Mar-2024 14:17:46.620 WARNING [ajp-nio-0.0.0.0-8765-Poller] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$Poller.events Invalid null socket channel while processing poller event

For what it's worth, I'm certain that Tomcat is actually receiving the requests, because the localhost_access_log file records the requests with a 500 response.
Is there a Tomcat setting I'm not aware of that prevents uncaught exceptions, or exceptions within Tomcat's own code, from being logged?
